# Single/ multiple imputation in post-selection/-regularization context

Tags: model-selection, regularization, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, selectiveinference

**Context of problem:**

In some situations researchers face **high-dimensional** problems with $p > n$, where $p$ is the number of covariates to be considered in a regression model and $n$ is the sample size. These problems may arise when many interactions, polynomial terms or splines have to be considered. When the aim is inference, e.g. the estimation of a treatment effect plus tests of the estimated effects, one may want to apply **post-selection/-regularization** methods to, first, identify a small set of covariates, which have relevant relationship between the target variable and the treatment variable, and, second, perform inference on the selected subset of covariates. Accordingly, the identities of the covariates in the **analysis model** are not known a priori, but only after the selection/ regularization step (given that the approximation to the "true" model works fine).

**The problem:**

If the data encompasses some variables with **missing values** and one decides to use some imputation technique, the question arises which variables to include in the **imputation model**. As far as I know the imputation model should contain at least all the covariates of the analysis model. But if the identities of the covariates to be included in the analysis model are not known beforehand, which variables should be included in the imputation model? As $p > n$ the choice may be difficult and if many, if not all, of the $p$ variables are considered in the imputation model, imputation may become unfeasible.

**The question:**

Is there any advise how to define the imputation model, when the analysis model is embedded in a post-selection/-regularization setting with high-dimensional data?